# With Mockito Trying to verify of a method call, inside which Executor.execute method is called

Tags: java, mockito, executor

this is the method call which should be verified, whether is called.

```
 Mockito.verify(messageHandler).handleMessage(message);
```

and this method is called inside prepareContext() method, which is called by executor.

```
executor.execute(() -> prepareContext())
```

And when I try to verify, I get an error, by saying,

```
wanted, but not invoked:
  messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
```

Actually I understand the reason why it's not being verified, because the verifier thread is not calling the handleMessage method, but instead it is called by another thread in reality.
So please, any suggestion of what should be done here, to be able to test this functionality.

Comment: I don't think the problem comes from the fact that `handleMessage` is executed in another thread. I suspect one of: 1. You verify before the method had a chance to execute. 2. System under test does not use your mock. 3. message does not implement equals.

Comment: One option might be to mock out the executor, and have the test version of the executor just execute the lambda it is given on the same thread rather than on a different thread.

Comment: @Lesiak lets exclude the version 3, because the error says "there was 0 interaction with this mock"

Comment: Ok, then try to exclude 2: add a breakpoint on the line when you execute desired method in prod code and on verify in test code. Inspect message handler - is it the same instance?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that your mock has not yet been called by the other thread when you verify. If you can create the executor in your test a an executor that executes the submitted task in the caller thread, and the problem is most likely solved. In the guava lib there is such an executor, that can be instantiated with MoreExecutors.directExecutor(), https://guava.dev/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/MoreExecutors.html#directExecutor()

Another approach is to *wait* for the verification to succeed. That can easily be achieved with the awaitility framework (http://www.awaitility.org). A good introduction can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/awaitility-testing